# Mixing huge number of audio files to stereo

Tags: audio, mixing

I am working on a project that requires an on-line service that should audio-mix user submitted 30-sec audio together in one stereo file. It would do daily preview bounces where new audio would be mixed with the last stereo version.
But for final full quality export with some adjustable options I might need to audio-mix huge amount of files anew (potentially 1,000,000+).

1. What is the best approach, and what mistakes should be avoided?
2. Are there any differences in terms of efficiency and audio quality in incremental mixing (wav 1 + wav 2 => new wav + wav 3 => new wav + wav 4 => new wav etc) vs mixing all at once (wav 1 + wav 2 + ... + wav n => new wav)?

Comment: _Any_ differences or _audible_ differences?

Comment: Any differences, meaning primarily off course audio quality and then efficiency in terms of processor juice needed.

Comment: My bet would be to mix them all at once, each one converted to double, but I don't have an exact reasoning at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at https://docs.audiostack.ai/docs/automixingservice - which might be able to solve your problem.